# Unity restricting Oculus Rift HMD to only allow for rotations and not position tracking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constraints, virtual-reality, oculus

I want to lock the player position of the Oculus rift in unity to be in one place the entire time. They are able to move their arms but can look with their head, they also cannot lean or turn their body. For example if they are sitting in a chair the player is locked to that chair and they cannot move from it but they can interact with objects in front of the chair using the controllers.

I have no clue how to do this. Either through code or the inspector. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included a solution to this on a different question I asked and answered. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114294/unity-final-vr-ik-asset-lock-person-in-sitting-position) for a solution to this.

Comment: Before people go on down voting this answer. I linked my own question and answer since the solutions are the exact same between the 2. If it is needed I will go ahead and repost the entire solution here.